# Increasing explosive power in clap push-ups?

Tags: strength, push-ups

How do you increase explosive power in your clap push-ups?  The goal isn't to do more of them or to build larger chest / arm muscles, but to launch oneself higher off the ground.

Comment: I'm not sure if fitness.stackexchange.com is the right place for this kind of question.  Please let me know if I should move this.

Comment: This is a very good question for this site. Keep them coming, if you've got more like it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 4 types of muscular development:

- **strength** - exerting maximum possible force
- **power** - exerting maximum possible force over the shortest duration possible
- **mass** - increasing the size of the muscle
- **endurance** - ability of cardiovascular system to supply oxygen to muscle

### Don't

Developing **strength** won't help the clap push-up, because you usually want to do more than one push up. Building **mass** doesn't help you get height on the push-up because the more massive you are, the more force gravity pushes you down (force = mass * gravity).

### Do

You will need to develop cardiovascular **endurance** to sustain you through a set of push-ups. The push up is a compound exercise, involving pecs, triceps, anterior deltoids, and core stability, which is a lot of muscles that are gasping for oxygen. To gain explosive power of the clap push-up, you obviously want to develop your **power**. Power training will propel you to new heights, literally.

The following chart will show you how to build endurance and power. Since push-ups are dependent on body weight, you won't be able to easily tune the load and rep range into the endurance and power zone. So I recommend using free weights for total control. You can do dumbbell bench presses, barbell bench presses, and dumbbell flies to develop chest power and endurance. Preferably, do these exercises on a flat bench to mimic the position of a clap push-up. However, the part of the clap push-up before your hands leave the ground does slightly resemble a decline press, so incorporate declines as well.

[image: training goal table]
<sub>Source: [Everything You Know About Fitness is a Lie](http://www.mensjournal.com/everything-you-know-about-fitness-is-a-lie/4)</sub>

Comment: +1 Good breakdown, and like the chart in particular. Especially the 8 day week for endurance. ;-)

Comment: How do you read the Load and Speed per rep? I'm thinking that if my max is 250lbs I should be doing 150lbs - 200lbs (Mass column) for load? What about speed? Does this chart apply to all weight training?

Comment: Also, is it possible to focus on two columns at the same time? How would that work, week 1 would be Mass and week 2 would be Strength? Edit: Nevermind, I just needed to read the link you provided.

Comment: This is amazing; not only will this help with the clap push up, it will also help with increasing vertical jump height.  Thank you!

Comment: @DustinDavis I'd really like to know the answer to what you asked so I asked in a separate question, did you find the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Ross Enamait provides a [very good video tutorial](http://youtu.be/YUSdLtzy4M8) on the triple clap pushup - something I have yet to achieve.

A great plyometric exercise that I'm looking into to help with the bottom part of the bench press.

Comment: Can you explain some of the steps here from that video?